# Get MongoDB Collection stats took more time using reactivestreams library

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my method to get Collection stas using reactivestreams library.

```
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;

com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient mongoReactveStreamsClient;

private CompletableFuture<String> getCollectionStats(String collectionName) {
    MongoDatabase database = mongoReactveStreamsClient.getDatabase(dbName);
    CompletableFuture<String> result = new CompletableFuture<>();

    database.runCommand(new Document("collStats", collectionName)).subscribe(new Subscriber<Document>() {
      private Subscription subscription;

      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        subscription = s;
        s.request(1);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Document document) {
        //subscription.cancel();
        result.complete(document.toJson());
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable t) {
        logger.info("onError [ERROR]----------------------------"+t.getMessage());
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

pom.xml
I have dependency from my pom.xml using 3.9.1 version of mongodb driver reactivestreams

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
 <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
 <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using vertx framework where it goes thread blocked issue by blocking get stats method over 1 min, In a list I have only 3 collection names from my mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way which is efficient

```
public Publisher<Document> getCollectionStats(MongoDatabase database, String collectionName, MongoDbCollectionStatsUnit scale) {
return database.runCommand(new Document("collStats", collectionName).append("scale", scale.size));
```

}

And to get list of Collection names

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
    
List<JsonObject> collectionsFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
MongoDatabase database = mongoReactveStreamsClient.getDatabase(dbName);
Flux.from(database.listCollectionNames())
    .filter(p -> p.contains(keyword))
    .flatMap(collectionName -> getCollectionStats(database, collectionName, scale))
    .subscribe(stats -> {
      stats.getInteger("size");
      stats.getInteger("count");
      stats.getInteger("storageSize");
      
    }, error -> {
      error.printStacktrace();
    });
```